# list.contains does not work

Tags: java, list, contains

I am trying to develop a TS3 Bot in Java with this API: https://github.com/TheHolyWaffle/TeamSpeak-3-Java-API

I have a list with all Server Groups that a Client have:

```
List<ServerGroup> playerGroups = TS3Bot.api.getServerGroupsByClientId(player.clientdbID);
```

And now I check if the List contains a Group:

```
if(!playerGroups.contains(TS3Bot.botGroups.get(1))){...}
```

And the result is false. I am 100% sure that this List contains the ServerGroup.

Already checked it out with Sysouts.

Here is the Link to the ServerGroup Class: https://github.com/TheHolyWaffle/TeamSpeak-3-Java-API/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/theholywaffle/teamspeak3/api/wrapper/ServerGroup.java

and this is just the ServerGroup Object.toString().

```
{iconid=0, savedb=1, sortid=0, name=Test 2, n_member_removep=100, sgid=98, type=1, n_member_addp=100, namemode=0, n_modifyp=100}
```

Comment: Have you overidden equals and hashcode in ServerGroup ?

Comment: `list.contains()` does indeed work. Please respond to @Jean-FrançoisSavard's comment. There has to be something you've done to disable the normal working of the `contains()` method.

Comment: You need to show the relevant parts of ServerGroup.

Comment: I have edited the post and there are now some new information inside. I have not overidden equals and hashcode, but ServerGroup is not my class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not forget to respect the `Object#equals(Object o)` contract

> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one. The equals
> method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object
> references:
>
> It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x,
> x.equals(x) should return true.
>
> It is symmetric: for any non-null
> reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only
> if y.equals(x) returns true.
>
> It is transitive: for any non-null
> reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and
> y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.
>
> It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple
> invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently
> return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on
> the objects is modified.
>
> For any non-null reference value x,
> x.equals(null) should return false. The equals method for class Object
> implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on
> objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this
> method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x
> == y has the value true).
>
> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as
> to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states
> that equal objects must have equal hash codes.